# Problema al compilar app Android en Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, android

Soy principiante en el mundo del desarrollo móvil, descargué **Xamarin Studio** (Mac) para comenzar a programar apps para los tres entornos, pero tengo un problema, creo, con el SDK de Android.

La primera vez que creé una app para Android, cuando quería observar la interfaz en Main.axml, me saltaba una ventana que decía algo así como que el SDK era antiguo y necesitaba actualizarlo a la versión 25.0.2 me parece. Abrí el Manager del SDK, y descargué todos los Extras, la última versión del Android SDK Tools, del Android DSK Build Tools, y del Android SDK Plataform Tools, y todo el pack Android 6.0.
Ahora funciona el diseñador, pero cuando compilo la aplicación surge este error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:
>   Error: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   com/android/dx/command/Main  :  Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>   (PruebaAndroidXamarin)

Comment: Puedes entrar a la configuración de Xamarin a la última versión del JDK. Generalmente ese error ocurre cuando tienes 2 versiones de java instaladas, ejemplo _jdk 1.8 & jdk 1.8_. Desinstala una

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**La versión 52.0 se refiere a la versión específica del JDK**

1. Xamarin Android para la version que estas usando requiere [JDK-8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) en su versión 1.8.
2. Otra de las soluciones que a mi me funciono, es bajarla el nivel de compilacion a tu aplicación, click derecho en tu solución android y vas a propiedades, ahi veras las versiones de compilacion yo las baje a 6.0 marshmallow, ya que por default creo que te esta compilando con Nougat, una ves que hagas eso, click derecho en tu solucion, **clean** y despues **build**, ya con eso debería compilar sin problemas de version.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. ¡Resolviste mi problema!